# Heroku Pipelines on AWS?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-ec2

The organization that I'm working for is migrating from Heroku to AWS, and we're missing the last piece of the puzzle - replicating Heroku Pipelines on AWS.

[Heroku pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines) are great, they let us:

- have multiple development stages: testing, staging, and production, each stage with their own environment vars. The testing stage can have multiple apps.
- hook up to Github: autodeploy to the production app any changes made to master branch, automatically create apps in the testing stage when we make a pull request ("Review Apps", very useful)
- automated tests: we don't do unit tests, we do high-level functionality tests against the website - every time a pull request is created and an app is created in the testing stage, a CLI script is executed from `composer.json` file, which uses Browserstack and emails us the results

So far, I've found these alternatives, but I don't think any of these fulfill all the requirements outlined above:

- [AWS CodePipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/welcome.html) (missing features we need)
- [Amazon Simple Workflow Service (SWF)](https://aws.amazon.com/swf/) (missing features we need)
- [lambdoku](https://github.com/kubek2k/lambdoku) (only for Lambda, we want to use EC2)
- [Harrow/Capistrano](https://harrow.io/features/)

The last item on the list, Harrow, seems to be as close as it gets to what we need, and I'm curious if anyone who has had the same (or very similar) requirements as me used it and was happy with it. I have a *feeling* this is what Heroku uses behind the scenes.

For production, we're gonna use a couple of EC2s behind a load balancer.
For testing and staging, we can either use one EC2 with multiple virtual environments within it (ie Docker) or use a t2.nano for each testing and staging app.

To summarize my question: what is the best tool, open source or commercial, that can replicate Heroku Pipelines?

Comment: I'm looking to do the same. Have you found a solution to your issue :) ?

Comment: @Mehdi hey man, I haven't. the company I work for decided to hire a devops engineer who setup a whole bunch of stuff (e.g. Jenkins)

Comment: Have you tried AWS Elastic Beanstalk alongside CodePipeline? Elastic Beanstalk is similar to Heroku in that you don't need to configure your EC2 instances.